# How to wait for asynchronous call to get finished in one-signal api

Tags: asynchronous, cross-domain, onesignal, window.parent

I am using One-signal API for notification . I want to get user Id from there API ,below is my code .

```
function setNotificationPermission()
{
    var id ;
    try
    {   
          OneSignal.push(["getUserId", function(userId) { 
          console.log("OneSignal User ID inside:"+ userId); 
            id = userId;
    }]); 
         console.log("OneSignal User ID outside:"+ id);
         window.parent.postMessage("Player ID"+id, "http://example.com");
    }
    catch(e){}
}
```

and i am getting answer as below

```
OneSignal User ID outside:
OneSignal User ID inside: f39fd4f1-406f-4c96-8365-5a471f77da3d
```

because method which i am calling of one signal is asynchronous so my window.parent.postMessage() method get executed before getting response . please tell me how to handle it? means how to wait until my OneSignal.push() get call completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because OneSignal's [getUserId()](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/website-sdk-api#getUserId) operates asynchronously, your `setNotificationPermission()` must *also* operate asynchronously. This means `setNotificationPermission()` must "wait" for `getUserId()` to complete before being able to reply.

OneSignal's `getUserId()` function accepts a callback and returns a [Promise](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/), so you can either:

- **Option 1:** Call `postMessage()` inside the `getUserId()` callback:

  `OneSignal.push(["getUserId", function(userId) { 
      window.parent.postMessage(userId);
  });`
- **Option 2:** Call `postMessage()` when the `getUserId()` [Promise resolves](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/):

  `OneSignal.push(function() {
      OneSignal.getUserId()
               .then(function(userId) {
                     window.parent.postMessage(userId);

                     });
  });`

The first option is the most straightforward. The first option calls `postMessage()` *after* the user ID has been retrieved, in the callback to `getUserId()`.